# Template overload based on condition

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

With type traits I can do the following:

```
template<typename Rect> Rect& move(Rect& rc, size_type<Rect> delta)
{
    rc.left += delta.width;
    rc.right += delta.width;
    rc.top += delta.height;
    rc.bottom += delta.height;
    return rc;
}
template<typename Rect> Rect& move(Rect& rc, point_type<Rect> to)
{
    int w = w(rc);
    int h = h(rc);
    rc.left = to.x;
    rc.top = to.y;
    rc.right = rc.left + w;
    rc.bottom = rc.top + h;
    return rc;
}
```

But how can I allow to pass any size and point types without changing name of the function? Apparently I **can't** do this:

```
template<typename Rect, typename Size> Rect& move(Rect& rc, Size delta);
template<typename Rect, typename Point> Rect& move(Rect& rc, Point to);
```

What I want to do is

```
template<typename Rect, typename Size /*if Size::width, use this*/> Rect& move(Rect& rc, Size size);
template<typename Rect, typename Point /*if Point::x, use this*/> Rect& move(Rect& rc, Point to);
```

I.e. choosing an overload depends on whether a template argument has a particular member. Is it possible in c++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I want to do is

> ```
> template<typename Rect, typename Size /*if Size::width, use this*/>
> Rect& move(Rect& rc, Size size);
> ```

> ```
> template<typename Rect, typename Point /*if Point::x, use this*/> 
> Rect& move(Rect& rc, Point to);
> ```

> I.e. choosing an overload depends on whether a template argument has a particular member. Is it possible in c++?

If you can use at least C++11... have you tried with SFINAE through trailing return type and `decltype()`?

I mean... something as

```
template <typename Rect, typename Size>
auto move (Rect & rc, Size size)
   -> decltype( size.width, rc );
// .............^^^^^^^^^^^  <-- note this

template <typename Rect, typename Point> 
auto move(Rect& rc, Point to)
   -> decltype( to.x, rc );
// .............^^^^^  <-- and note this
```

Obviously this doesn't works if you call `move()` with a second argument with both a `with` and a `x` member: the compiler doesn't know which one `move()` select.

How it works?

It's simple: the main word is SFINAE, that mean Substitution Failure Is Not An Error.

Take in count that `decltype()` return the type of the contained expression, so (for example) from

```
   decltype( size.width, rc );
```

the comma operator discard `size.width`, **if** **available** (this is the important point!), and remain `rc`, so `decltype()` return the type of `rc` (if `size.width` exist!).

But what happens if `size.width` doesn't exist?

You have a "substitution failure". That "is not an error" but remove this overloading version of `move()` from the set of available `move()` functions.

Comment: Interesting, this works. Though, sadly, it's hard to understand for me now how the compiler works in this case.

Comment: Can I mix this with type traits? Like this `template<typename Rect> auto convert(Rect rc) -> decltype(rc.left, convert_type<Rect>{}/*rvalue reference, not what I want*/)`

Comment: @olekstolar - Yes, you can mix: `decltype()` only return the type of the expression; isn't important if the type is obtained from a type traits. In the meantime, I've improved the answer, trying to explain how it works.

Comment: After some reading I find out that `decltype` returns T for rvalue expressions, T& for lvalue and T&& for xvalue. `T{}` is definitely an rvalue. Also _"The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand"_ — from cppreference.

Comment: @olekstolar - Take in count that I've used `decltype( t )` instead of `decltype( T{} )`; `decltype( t )` is `T &`. Anyway, you can also add an `&` after `decltype()`: `decltype( T{} ) &`.  En passant: avoid `decltype( T{} )`, when possible; use `decltype( std::declval<T>() )` instead (that is `T &`); so it works also when `T` isn't default constructible.

Comment: Though it seems that I need to use `std::remove_reference` in order to return by value, isn't it?

Comment: @olekstolar - Yes... the use of `std::remove_reference` should works... but you can also declare a function similar to `std::declval()` that doesn't add the reference.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thanks!